How to choose a feature as an offset in GLM Binary Regression
Is there any statistical test to determine that Feature A should be an offset instead of Feature B and Feature C.
From what I understand, if in insurance modelling, usually, offset has a connection with exposure. But what would be an offset in fraud detection or any other binary classification ? One that comes to mind is the amount of transfer could be an offset. But how to proof or give evidence that the amount of transfer is better use as an offset.

Please look at our tag info on offset for guidance. If the regression coefficient must be exactly 1 given the subject matter and the nature of the model, it's an offset. Otherwise it isn't.
